# SQL to select subCode and its score from results database and output it as one string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a results table with the following description. I need a way to loop through the table and get subCode and grade of a certain admNo and put them together as one string in order to send it via SMS. The message content should look like this:

```
2129 CAT1 101 A- 102 C+ 121 A 231 C+.
```

Contents of results table...

```
id  admNo   examtyp subCode  termId formId  streamId score  grade   points  year
1   2129    CAT1    101      1  3   0   87  A-  11  2013
1   2129    CAT1    102      1  3   0   65  C+  7   2013
1   2129    CAT1    121      1  3   0   90  A   12  2013
1   2129    CAT1    231      1  3   0   67  C+  7   2013
1   2129    CAT1    233      1  3   0   66  C+  7   2013
1   2129    CAT1    311      1  3   0   65  C+  7   2013
1   2129    CAT1    313      1  3   0   90  A   12  2013
1   2129    CAT1    565      1  3   0   60  C   6   2013
2   4093    CAT1    101      1  3   0   0   C+  7   2013
2   4093    CAT1    102      1  3   0   70  B-  8   2013
```

The above table stores subject scores of students. If there is a way I can loop through the array after fetching then that would work too.

Comment: Why does the example SMS only show 4 scores, when there are 8 for that `admNo` in the example table above?

Comment: no that was just an example of what i want but the actual sms should have all the subcode and the grades

Comment: @samlebo . . . Why include the column name for the subcode?  You can just have a column for "101" and another for "102" and so on.

Comment: @Gordon that wold not work because the subcodes are dynamic since they represent the subjects that a student takes

Comment: @samlebo . . . The resulting query that you are asking for would have a variable number of columns.  That isn't allowed for a SQL query.  You have three choices.  Use dynamic SQL (a prepare statement); concatenate multiple values together into a single column; or have a maximum number of columns and hope the results fit in.

Comment: Where are you sending the SMS from? It would be much easier to do this after fetching all columns from the database. This wouldnt be incredibly difficult in PHP for example... Or Python even easier actually

Comment: I am inserting the sms to send into ozekimessageout table using php codeigniter framework

Comment: Could you clarify this is your Question. So to check I get what you mean, you KNOW the admNo you want to get the "sms" string for. You want to find a way of creating this string, then insert it into another "ozekimessageout" table in the database?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have no knowledge of dynamic sql

Comment: @0orebelius0o yes thats what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the message content to look like your example, you can do that with one row per `admNo`/`examtyp`:

```
select concat(admNo, ' ', examtyp, ' ', 
              group_concat(concat(subcode, ' ', grade) separator ' '),
              '.'
             ) MessageLine
from Results r
group by admNo, examtyp
```

Comment: Wow did not realise you could do something like that in pure sql. Well played sir

Comment: @o0rebelious0o there are geneouses here much appreciation to them

Answer (score 0):

This PHP code does what you want:

```
$admNo = 4093;

$DB_NAME = "*dbname*";
$DB_HOST = "*hostname*";
$DB_USER = "*dbusername*";
$DB_PASS = "*dbpassword*";
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE admNo=$admNo";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
$total = $mysqli->affected_rows;
$linea = $result->fetch_assoc();
$string = $linea['admNo'].' '.$linea['examtyp'].' '.$linea['subCode'].' '.$linea['grade'].' ';
for($i = 0; $i < $total-1; $i++){
    $linea = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $string .= $linea['subCode'].' '.$linea['grade']. ' ';
}
print $string;
```

OUTPUT:

```
4093 CAT1 101 C+102 B-
```

This PHP code will populate the $string output with the format shown in the output, creating it from all entries for the admNo in the table.  You can then do an SQL insert using the string to put it into the sms table as you need to

This what you needed?

Comment: @o0rebelius0o i need this: 2129 CAT1 101 A- 102 C+ 121 A 231 C+.